# AutoSize / Scrollbar in DataChart (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a DataChart (in Windows Forms) which gets different Data from a Database. The Datarows can be between 0 and N rows. In which N values can be up to 30.000 rows of data max.

As you see on the Screenshot, there are 64 rows of data and it looks not very good. The DataChart should be **autosizable** *and/or* **scrollable** that there will fit all rows into.

[image]

(sorry I can't show the whole text, because it is business secret data)

I want either the DataChart to be **scrollable** or to make the DataChart **autosizeable** and add it into a *scrollable* *Panel*.

I tried to add a scrollbar to my DataChart but nothing changed...

```
With DataChart
    .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.ScrollBar.Size = 10
    .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.All
    .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = True
    .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.ScrollBar.Enabled = True
End With
```

Is there a way to solve my Problem? If you have C# Code please post it too. Thanks!

Comment: The are maybe more issues but the 1st one is that you are confusing x- andy-axes. (You have a bar chart, which them switched !!!)

Comment: Please don't look at the axes, I tried this code with all 4 axes (X, Y, X2, Y2) and it made no difference.

Comment: That still make the posted code wrong. You may also want to look into [axisscaleview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisscaleview(v=vs.110).aspx)  /(esp. Position and Size). Remember to use the x-axis!

Comment: Ok thx for that tip. I will try to fix my code and will post this in here if I have solved it. Do I only have to look at the 'ChartAreas()' - Settings or do I have to change some Settings in the 'Series'-Settings, too ?

Comment: And my second question is: Do I have to put the data FIRST and then change this settings, or do I have to change this settings BEFORE putting data into it? I'm asking because I read something, that I have to do some settings before putting data into it, and make some settings after putting data into it.

Comment: As for zooming: You can do that by the XAxis alone. [See here for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+zoom+) - You can change settings and add data in any order.